# How to remove white space before the colon in "OTHER : example example" to be "OTHER: example example" - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove white space before the colon. I read up on RegEx but do not understand it.

In my DF, I have a column with records like "OTHER : text" and just need to remove the white space before colon.

Answer (score 0):

The `str.replace` method should do it.

```py
example = 'OTHER : example example'
df = pd.DataFrame({'example': [example for _ in range(10)]})
df['example'] = df['example'].str.replace('OTHER :', 'OTHER:')
```

Comment: Will this keep whatever text follows after the "OTHER:"? Basically there are are bunch of records like "other : random text here", and I need to keep all the text after and just delete that white space before the colon.

Comment: This would keep the random text.  By default the method will replace *all* instances of `OTHER :` with `OTHER:`.  If you only wanted the first instance to be changed then pass the argument `n=1`.


`df['example'] = df['example'].str.replace('OTHER :', 'OTHER:', n=1)`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub("( )+:",":",yourText)
```

"( )+:" - all multiple spaces folowing colon
":"     - replace with colon

or just simple

```
re.sub(" :",":",yourText)
```